# Getting the wrong output in .html.erb file

Tags: html, file, rubygems, erb

I am using the 'active_shipping' gem. When I am using the .rb file with the following line

```
  puts res.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect 
  {|rate| [rate.service_name,
  (@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD)
   *    (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)]},
```

I get the following output:

[image]

When, however, I use the same line in my .html.erb file

```
<%= res.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect 
{|rate| [rate.service_name, 
(@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD)
* (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)]}%>,
```

I   get the following output in my view:

[image]

Can someone help me please with this issue. How do I display text properly in my .html.erb file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kathryn, I did change the code to:

```
<p><%res.rates.sort_by(&:price).each do |rate|%>
 <%=  rate.service_name%>,
 <%=(@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD)
  *  (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)%> </p><br/>
 <%end%>
```

I got the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby objects are not being shown in erb, I think because you do not have enough delimiters. Try this instead:

```
<% res.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect %> 
<%= {|rate| [rate.service_name, 
  (@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD)
  * (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)]} %>
```